# What is the correct way of setting the current thread NSRunLoop to run in a certain mode until I decide to stop it?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nsrunloop

I want to mimic the UIScrollView behavior where the current thread RunLoop mode changes to UITrackingRunLoopMode when you drag the scrollView, and back to NSDefaultRunLoopMode when you stop dragging.

I want to do it with my own class, though, dragging around views... Right now I'm using this code

```
while (_draggingView && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```

When I stop dragging, _draggingView changes to nil so I stop looping in that mode. Is there a more elegant/better way of doing this?

How is UIScrollView doing it? Input sources?

Thank you

Comment: I fear that it is not possible to change the run loop mode without using some private API. Could you elaborate more what are you trying to do?

Comment: why do you want to change the mode of the runloop? is there any real problem or you want to learn more about the runloop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CFRunLoopStop`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopStop) to force a run loop to return.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetMain());
}
```

Comment: I don't want to stop a runLoop. I just want to change the mode.

Comment: You can't change the mode.  You run it in a mode.  When you want to run in a different mode, you stop the current run and start again in the new mode (or just return and let the outer invocation of `CFRunLoopRun` resume).

Answer (score -1):

You can use *Decelerated* methods.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

After we drag the scroll view, it starts decelerating, so, these methods might be of use to you.

Comment: No, that has no use. I have no UISCrollView, I just want to change the NSRunLoop of the main thread to work in UITrackingRunLoopMode whenever I want (Just like UIScrollView does when you drag). But thanks anyway.